# ASP.NET MVC6 dynamic navigation on a page

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an application with ASP.NET Core (MVC 6) where administrator can specify what the top level navigation would look like. For the sake of simplicity, let's say that he owns a bakery and wants his top level navigation to look like this:

1. Home
2. Cakes

   a) Diary-free

   b) Chocolate

   c) Fruity
3. Sweets
4. Cookies

   a) Chocolate-chip

   b) Raw

   c) Vegan

Once he has decided what the navigation would look like (as shown above) he will save it and these will be stored in the database.

Now, when anyone visits this website, the program needs to retrieve the 'layout' from the database and based on the returned values needs to build the top level navigation for the user.

As I am still a newbie in ASP.NET, the question that arises is - Would this be a good approach? The problem I foresee with this would be, that none of these webpages would actually exist (there would be no **/Cakes/diary-free.html** webpage as this only exists in the database) and therefore how would the navigation work like?

Any help or suggestion in this matter would be more than appreciated.

Comment: MVC works with controllers and action methods that return view, not with `.html` files. What are you expecting to display if a user were to click on say "Diary-free"?

Comment: We will go to the database and retrieve items for this particular selection. In this cake it could be pictures of diary free cakes with prices, names, ...

Comment: Now when I am thinking about it, it seems to me that I actually need to use Angular.JS and create single page application. Am I correct about this?

Comment: Creating a single page app does nothing to solve this. Best guess is you want a CMS (Content Management System) but your question is far too broad for SO.